# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition recording a web test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

In Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition, while recording a web test in IE 11, in the code generated, I see the request generated for each resource on the web page except the video file present in the web page.  I can view the video file in IE 11 when I browse to the URL, but in the code generated while recording, I do not see the request that downloads the video (.mp4) file.  Is there any way to record that and include that request too in the code generated?

Thanks,
Indu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many files (such as CSS, Javascript, images and videos etc) are normally not explicitly included in the recorded test. These files, or more accurately the requests to get them, are termed "dependent requests". Many dependent requests are detected by Visual Studio when it runs the web test by processing the responses. The `Parse dependent requests` property of the request (in the `.webtest` file) can be changed to `false` to prevent the detection of dependent requests.

For your test I would expect the test to detect the video at run time of the test and so download it. If that does not happen then the request can be added explicitly via the context (right click) menu command `Add dependent request`.

Comment: The video is downloaded using createobjecturl, perhaps that is why it does not generate the code.

Comment: @Indu, if `createobjecturl` is a Javascript routine then remember that web tests do not execute Javascript, or any other scripting language. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404678(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL it is a web api